# How do I get a Samsung SCX 5737FW printer working?

Tags: printing

can anyone please help? I am trying to install samsung printer SCX 5737FW on Ubuntu 11.10, but when I plug in the usb cable it tries to look for the driver, but can't find it. Indeed the webpage

http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/print-solutions/print-solutions/mono-multi-function-products/SCX-5737FW/SEE-spec

tells me that the printer is supported up to Ubuntu 10. This true because it installs
perfectly on my other machine with ubuntu 9.

Can anyone help please? Thanks

Comment: support page listing the drivers here: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/SCX-5737FW/SEE-downloads?isManualDownload=true

Comment: thanks a lot BlueXrider. I have found the driver on your link, it is the generic Linux 3.00.85 Unified driver.

It is tar.gz: I have unpacked it, but when should I do at this
stage? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Samsung Unified Linux Driver v3.00.xx Directly
This gives all instructions on installation.

http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/smfpv3.html

Comment: Hi BlueXrider, the repository does not have the driver exactly for my printer Samsung SCX 5737FW, so I have used the driver for SCX 5X30...everything seemed ok but then when I try to print, I get a window ''Authentication required for printing document.. and there is a blank box asking me for a password, I have tried my ubuntu password, but it does nto work. Thanks again for your help